# Facebook PHP SDK and Wordpress Error

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, session, sdk

I have a developer environment setup with WAMP, Wordpress, and PHPEdit IDE. I use the Facebook, Twitter, and YouTube API's in a sidebar. I'm using Facebook's PHP SDK to display information(no login or admin functions). Since the FB SDK and WP use session_start() I get the following warning:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   C:\wamp\www\dfi\wp-content\themes\DFI\header.php:12) in
>   C:\wamp\www\dfi\wp-content\themes\DFI\api\facebook.php on line 36

I'm trying to figure this out by using the warning output but it doesn't help considering the following. I know about clearing white space and characters before and after `<?php ?>` and placing session_start() before any http output. I use unix line enders and UTF8 encoding without BOM. My host server is not set up for output_buffering.

header.php line 11 to 13

```
11 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
12 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes();?>>
13 <head>
```

It looks like the warning comes from inline php code. I don't know what I can do to fix this line.

facebook.php line 34 to 37

```
34    public function __construct($config) {
35    if (!session_id()) {
36      session_start();
37    }
```

I don't think I can stop either FB or WP from calling session_start() without breaking everything. How do I make Wordpress and Facebook play nicely together without this error?

EDIT:
To stop the warning from displaying I put @ in front of session_start().

```
public function __construct($config) {
    if (!session_id()) {
      @session_start();
    }
```

Its only a workaround and I would still like to find the root of the problem.

Comment: Where are you including the PHP Facebook instance.

Comment: I've tried require_once and locate_template(WP function) at the top of functions.php and the first line of header.php with no luck. I think its because wordpress calls session_start way before these pages are referenced.

Comment: Correct, see if this points you in the right direction http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43627/conditionally-loading-facebook-php-sdk-in-shortcode

Comment: The question refers to the same session_start() warning but doesn't address it. In the last example he calls `require 'facebook.php';` and then only creates an instance of the facebook class with his php short code called in some random place. If I knew where he was calling everything that might give me a better insight.

Comment: Left a comment on the post bringing this question to his attention.

Comment: @Gecko it does address the problem specifically actually, you may want to re-read my answer there. I am defining the facebook class in the `wp` hook (`$this->facebook`), and then using it in the shortcode. I can `require` the class anywhere so that it's in scope. Since it was defined in the `wp` hook, there were no errors, and I can now use `$this->facebook` anywhere in my class.

Comment: Start out above the `__construct()` function with `public $facebook = null`, then define it in the `wp` hook (`$this->facebook = new Facebook( array( 'appId' => $app_id, 'secret' => $app_secret ) );`), and then use it wherever (`if( !is_null( $this->facebook ) ) $this->facebook->getUser();`) -- This is assuming you're using a class to do this.

Comment: After reading it again, I have a better understanding of what you're doing with `add_action( 'wp', array( &$this, 'define_facebook' ) );`. I was confused what was causing the error. I thought it was `require` but it turns out that creating the facebook object is the problem. You can post your comment as an answer if you like. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discovered in your comments, the issue isn't about including the PHP file, rather it is where you define the class. Creating the instance of the Facebook class can be safely done (as far as I know, it works for me) in the `wp` hook. This will allow you to define the instance of the class before any HTML output, then you can use that variable anywhere in your class.

You do however want to be sure to only include the class once, but you can instantiate the class as many times as you want.

Here's a basic example to get you started:

```
if( !class_exists( 'Facebook' ) ) {
    require_once 'facebook.php';
}

if( !class_exists( 'YourClass' ) ) {

    class YourClass {

        public $facebook = null;

        public function __construct() {

            add_action( 'wp', array( $this, 'define_facebook' ) );
            add_action( 'any_hook_after_wp', array( $this, 'example_usage' ) );

        }

        public function define_facebook() {
            global $post;

            // Assuming you are using post meta for the app ID and secret, you can use other methods though
            $app_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'appId', true );
            $app_secret = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'appSecret', true );

            $this->facebook = new Facebook( array( 'appId' => $app_id, 'secret' => $app_secret ) );

        }

        public function example_usage() {

            if( !is_null( $this->facebook ) ) {

                // Lets see what we have here..
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r( $this->facebook );
                echo "</pre>";
                exit;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I've adapted this code to my wordpress site and it works like a charm. Since I'm not dynamically loading different instances of facebook I decided to contain the app ID, secret, configuration etc. in private static variables. I just started building rep, if you could up vote this question, I think that I would get enough points so that I can do the same for the answer. Thank you Jared.

Answer (score 0):

You can using Hook Action init to check session_id exist or not.

```
// add it into functions.php in theme folder
add_action('init', 'themename_wp_session_start');
function themename_wp_session_start(){
    if( !session_id() ){
        session_start();
    }
}
```